# Wordpress plugin development: What hook to use to have a popup displayed when user arrives to the homepage?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I started developing a relatively simple WP plugin that should enable showing a popup box on the homepage when a new visitor arrives.

I will have many more questions on the same topic as I advance through the dev stages but for now, I'm stuck in the beginning.

I'm not sure what hook should I use to have such box displayed on the homepage (page centered)?

I've tried using action hook 'init' but that somehow interferes with a class declaration in wp_admin_bar.

Is there a suitable **filter** hook to accomplish this?

Thanks!

Comment: OK, in the meantime I decided to try get_footer action hook. It works, my sample string is there. But what is the best practice to get the box to the center of the page?
I'm thinking about absolutely positioning the box (related to the near-footer parent div)?

Comment: Your latter question is unrelated to WP hook, this is a CSS problem common to all lightbox and modal.

Comment: Not sure as you're writing a plugin if there's a hook, but in a theme there are `is_home()` and `is front page()` functions one could use to display the relevant HTML code. Or the class `.home`, even simpler but you may not want to include few kB of JS on each other page of your site.

Comment: I went with using a jQuery script that injects a div (container) just after the <body> tag. I still use get_footer() hook and that generates my markup (another div) before closing </div> of the main content section of the page. But another line in the aforementioned jquery script takes that markup and moves it into the div right after the <body> tag. So I end-up with what I initially wanted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following plug-in as a guide and pick out the pieces of code you need, it seems to accomplish what you're looking for.

[WP Greet Box](http://omninoggin.com/wordpress-plugins/wp-greet-box-wordpress-plugin/)

Comment: I'm developing a plugin myself, so I don't need another one. Thanks for your reply though. See my comment above about how I solved my problem.